# Product of non-empty proper subsets is never open in an infinite product topology

Tags: general-topology, product-space

If $\{X_i\}_i\in I$ are topological spaces, $I$ is infinite, $U_i \subset X_i$ are proper open subsets, then $\prod U_i$ is not open in $\prod X_i$

This is a question from my H.W. assignment. I’ve been staring at this question for 3-4 hours but I couldn’t even find a way to initiate the question. I would appreciate any help or hint to solve the question.

Thanks.

Comment: Let $U = \prod_i U_i$ and $X = \prod_i X_i$. What does it mean to say $U$ is *open* in the product topology on $X$?

Comment: U is open in product topology on X if every point of U is an interior point?

Comment: To be precise, if $x=(x_1,x_2 . . .) \in U$ then there exist open sets $B_i$, where $x_i  \in B_i$ such that $x\in (B_1,B_2, . . .) \subseteq U $

Comment: Hmm what does an interior point mean here? I suggest thinking about the following: $U$ is open in $X$ iff it's a union of intersections of finitely many sets of the form $p_i^{-1}(V_i)$, where $V_i$ is an open set in $X_i$ and $p_i$ is the canonical projection $X \to X_i$.

Comment: You should first write down your definition of  the product topology.

Comment: What is a *proper* subset?  Is the empty set a proper subset?

Comment: Note that the hypothesis that the $U_i$'s are open is useless. Also,   your question should be readable (hence here: repeated) in your text, not only from your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T_i$ be the topology on $X_i.$ The product topology $T$ on $X=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is defined as the weakest topology such that each projection $p_j:X\to X_j$ is continuous. So when $c_j\in T_j$ then $p_j^{-1}c_j=\prod_{i\in I}A_i\in T$, where $A_j=c_j,$ and $A_i=X_i$ for each $i\ne j.$

So we have $S=\bigcup_{j\in I}\{p_j^{-1}c_j:c_j\in T_j\}\subseteq T.$

Now $S$ is a sub-base for a topology $T'$ on $X,$ and $$T'\subseteq T$$ because $S\subseteq T.$

Now each $p_j$ is continuous with respect to the topology $T'$ so by the $\subseteq$-minimality ("weakest") definition of $T,$ we have $$T\subseteq T'.$$ Therefore $T'=T.$

Consider any  $U\in T$. Since $S$ is a sub-base for $T$, we have $U\supseteq\bigcap_{i\in E}\;p_i^{-1}c_i$ for some finite $E\subset I$ with  each $c_i\in T_i.$ So $U\supseteq\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ where $A_i=c_i$ if $i\in E,$ and $A_i=X_i$ if $i\not\in E.$ Now $E$ is finite so if $I$ is infinite then $\{i\in I: A_i=X_i\}\ne\emptyset.$