# Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ are open sets in product topology?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

This question is likely to be trivial, but I'm confused by it. I will leave here a couple of the examples my teacher left  here, so I can guide myself through the others.

Which of these subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}=\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times...$ are open in product topology?

$U=\{(x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{\omega} : x_n > 0 $ for $ n/2 \in \mathbb{N}\}$

$U_k=\{(x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{\omega}: x_k\neq0\}$

What must happen for the subsets of the "pre-projection" to not form a subbasis?

Comment: What do you call "the subsets of the pre-projection"?

Comment: The sets $p_{\beta}^{-1}(A)$ with A being open intervals of projection $p_{\beta}(U)$. The last question may not make sense. I'm having some trouble understanding why the definition  of the product topology is the way it is.

Comment: I understand "The sets $p^{-1}_\beta(A)$ with $A$ being open intervals", but neither "of projection $p_\beta(U)$" (which $U$? same as above?) nor "what must happen".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U_k$ is open and even belongs to the subbasis defining the product topology, since it is equal to $p_k^{-1}(\Bbb R^*)=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$ where $X_k$ is the open subset $\Bbb R^*\subset\Bbb R$ and the other $X_n$'s are equal to $\Bbb R.$

$U$ is not open, for the same reason as [a product of non-empty proper open  subsets is never open in an infinite product topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4550898): since $U\ne\varnothing,$ if it were open, it would contain some element $\bigcap_{n\le N}p_n^{-1}(X_n)=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$ of the basis, where the $X_n$'s are non-empty open subsets of $\Bbb R$ for $n\le N,$ and $X_n=\Bbb R$ for $n>N,$ but the latter is incompatible with the definition of $U.$

"The sets $p^{-1}_\beta(A)$ with $A$ being open intervals" form a subbasis of the product topology on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}.$